# what is referring to a directory called apache 192.168.1.12 home 192.168.1.12/mydirectory alternate directory

Tags: linux, debian, apache-httpd

I have a virtual machine, bitnami linux debian, magento stack

192.168.1.12 it points to my htdocs directory, that works.

The stack has another directory magento, when I enter 192.168.1.12/magento I want it to go to that directory which has its own path.

I am not sure what this would be called. Maybe its a virtual directory, versus a virtual host?

Maybe its UserDir?

Sorry if this has been asked before.

Any help pointing me in the right direction would be helpful. Thanks

Comment: Read up on [`Alias`](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_alias.html#alias)

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

No, in Apache's lingvo that would be called "alias". Also known as "URL mapping"

Inside a web-server definition you can have any number of commands like:

```
Alias "/docs" "/var/web"
Alias "/project" "/data/project"
Alias "/mynas" "/mnt/nas"
```

The first parameter is URL part, and the second is an absolute path in your file system.

For detailed documentation go here: https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/urlmapping.html

Virtual hosts solve different problem. What if you have several IP addresses on a single machine? Or you want one web-site respond to a port 80, and another to a port 8080? Certainly, this can be solved by running several apache processes, each listening on a different IP:port pair. But it would eat a lot of memory and processing power. That is where "virtual hosts" are coming in. You can define as many virtual hosts as needed, but they all be served by a single apache process.

Comment: Awesome I will check that URL mapping, makes sense, I just could not think of how it was worded. Thanks again.